# SDK Facebook Missing redirect_uri parameter / An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this code in order to retrieve the last 5 Facebook user posts and publish them on another website:

```
require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{xxxxxxxxxxxx}',
  'app_secret' => '{xxxxxxxxxxxxxx}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me/feed?fields=id,message&amp;limit=5');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

// Page 1
$feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();

foreach ($feedEdge as $status) {
  var_dump($status->asArray());
}

// Page 2 (next 5 results)
$nextFeed = $fb->next($feedEdge);

foreach ($nextFeed as $status) {
  var_dump($status->asArray());
}
```

But I get an error message:

> Graph returned an error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

How can I solve this?

I changed the code:

```
require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '{*****}',
'app_secret' => '{******}',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
]);


try {
$tolken = $fb->get("/oauth/access_token?client_id={****}&amp;client_secret={***********}&amp;grant_type=client_credentials");
$response = $fb->get("/me/feed?fields=id,message&amp;limit=5&amp;access_token=$tolken");
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

// Page 1
$feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();

foreach ($feedEdge as $status) {
var_dump($status->asArray());
}

// Page 2 (next 5 results)
$nextFeed = $fb->next($feedEdge);

foreach ($nextFeed as $status) {
var_dump($status->asArray());
}
```

And now the error is:

> Graph returned an error: Missing redirect_uri paramete

But in dashboARd/setting/advanced I had set 'URI di reindirizzamento OAuth validi'.

Comment: Use an active access token

Comment: of course, but I don't know how :)